# No soy capaz de cargar información de un archivo

Tags: java, eclipse

Hola a todos tengo un problema tengo un programama el cual me interesa guardar la información de un arralist llamado Usuarios. El problema surge a la hora de querer cargar esos datos guardados de nuevo en el arraylist que no se como hacerlo para que no me de error el código. Os dejo el código y Gracias de antemano.

```
System.out.print("Guardando datos en el fichero datos.dat.. ");

ObjectOutputStream escribiendoFichero = new ObjectOutputStream( 
        new FileOutputStream("datos.dat") );
escribiendoFichero.writeObject(Usuarios);
escribiendoFichero.close();

System.out.println("ok!");
System.out.print("Leyendo ArrayList del fichero datos.dat.. ");

ObjectInputStream leyendoFichero = new ObjectInputStream( 
        new FileInputStream("datos.dat") );
Usuarios = leyendoFichero.readObject("datos.dat"); //El problema me lo da en esta linea
leyendoFichero.close();

System.out.println("ok!");
System.out.println("Datos leídos del fichero:");
```

Comment: Debes de agregar la traza del error para verificar, y agregar el tipo de datos que es `Usuarios`, recuerda que mientras más detallado seas más fácil recibirás una respuesta y evitaras que se cierre tu pregunta por falta de información.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de la línea es porque al ejecutar el método `readObject()` no necesitas especificar el nombre del archivo porque eso lo realizaste en el paso anterior.

```
 // Aquí ya especificas el nombre del archivo
 ObjectInputStream leyendoFichero = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("datos.dat") );
 
 // Aqui solo haces un cast del tipo de objeto que sea `Usuarios`
 Usuarios = (String[]) leyendoFichero.readObject();
```

Como puedes ver tu error es porque no debes de especificar el nombre del archivo al ejecutar `readObject()`, lo que tienes que tener en cuenta es que el `cast` debe de ser según el tipo de dato que almacenaste,  en mi ejemplo `Usuarios` es un array de String por lo tanto realizo un cast del objeto `(String[])` si `Usuarios` fuese un arraya de un objeto `Usuarios` el cash seria `(Usuarios[])`.

> Como recomendación cambia el nombre de la variable `Usuarios` a `usuario` las variables siempre se escriben con el inicio en minúscula como convención y buena práctica.